# How to convert array values to comma seperated string based on specified given array values..?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, implode, array-column

I have the array as specified below

```
Array
(
  [5] => Array
  (
    [id] => 5
    [first_name] => Diyaa
    [profile_pic] => profile/user5.png
  )

  [8] => Array
  (
    [id] => 8
    [first_name] => Raj
    [profile_pic] => profile/user8.png
  )

  [12] => Array
  (
    [id] => 12
    [first_name] => Vanathi
    [profile_pic] => profile/user12.png
  )

  [15] => Array
  (
    [id] => 15
    [first_name] => Giri
    [profile_pic] => profile/user15.png
  )

  [19] => Array
  (
    [id] => 19
    [first_name] => Mahesh
    [profile_pic] => profile/user19.png
  )
)
```

I have another array as given below

```
Array
(
  [0] => 8
  [1] => 15
  [2] => 19
)
```

I want the `first_name` from the **first array**, based on **second array** values => **8, 15 and 19**.
So I need **Raj,Giri,Mahesh** as output as comma separated string.
How to get this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will work for you :-

```
$array1 = array_column($array, 'first_name','id');
$array2 = [8,15,19];
$names = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
$names = implode(',',$names);
echo $names;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$namesArr = [];
foreach ($wantedIds as $wantedId) {
    $namesArr[] = $array[$wantedId]['first_name'];
}
$namesStr = implode(',', $namesArr);

echo $namesStr; // Returns 'Raj,Giri,Mahesh'
```

I defined `$array` and `$wantedIds` as below:

```
$array = [
    5 => [
        'id'          => 5,
        'first_name'  => 'Diyaa',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user5.png',
    ],
    8 => [
        'id'          => 8,
        'first_name'  => 'Raj',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user8.png',
    ],
    12 => [
        'id'          => 12,
        'first_name'  => 'Vanathi',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user12.png',
    ],
    15 => [
        'id'          => 15,
        'first_name'  => 'Giri',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user15.png',
    ],
    19 => [
        'id'          => 19,
        'first_name'  => 'Mahesh',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user19.png',
    ],
];

$wantedIds = [8, 15, 19];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using `array_column` and `array_intersect_key` to obtain desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805870)

```
$result=array();
$result=  array_column($array, "first_name","id");
$result=array_intersect_key ($result,  array_flip($values));
echo implode(",",$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$names = [];
foreach ($MainArray as $aIndex => $aPayload) // loop over the key and values of the first array
{
    foreach ($searchArray as $b) // loop over your search array (we don't care about the indicies)
    {
        if ($aIndex == $b) // match up the index of the first array with the values of the second array
        {
            $names[] = $b['first_name'];// append the name to the return array
            break; // since we've found the index break out of the inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $abc = [
        ['id' => 5, 'firstname' => 'Diyya', 'profile_pic' => 'profile/user5.png'],
        ['id' => 8, 'firstname' => 'Raj', 'profile_pic' => 'profile/user8.png'],
        ['id' => 12, 'firstname' => 'Vanathi', 'profile_pic' => 'profile/user12.png']
    ];

    $d = [8, 5, 12];

    $output = [];
    foreach ($abc as $user) {
        if (in_array($user['id'], $d)) {
            $output [] = $user['firstname'];
        }
    }
    echo implode(",", $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers that are wise to use `array_intersect_key()` and `array_column()` however, they use them in the wrong order.  The array should be filtered first, so that `array_column()` is processing a smaller array.  Also, because your subarrays already have keys that represent the `id` value inside of them, there is no need to use the `index_key` parameter of `array_column()`.  This is going to be the simplest, most direct one-liner you can make:

Inputs:

```
$array = [
    5 => [
        'id'          => 5,
        'first_name'  => 'Diyaa',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user5.png',
    ],
    8 => [
        'id'          => 8,
        'first_name'  => 'Raj',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user8.png',
    ],
    12 => [
        'id'          => 12,
        'first_name'  => 'Vanathi',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user12.png',
    ],
    15 => [
        'id'          => 15,
        'first_name'  => 'Giri',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user15.png',
    ],
    19 => [
        'id'          => 19,
        'first_name'  => 'Mahesh',
        'profile_pic' => 'profile/user19.png',
    ],
];
$search_keys=[8, 15, 19];
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af4be6bb8b99efe83c125eac14726e9772dd1ed5)):

```
echo implode(',',array_column(array_intersect_key($array,array_flip($search_keys)),'first_name'));
```

Explanation:

- First flip the keys/values from `$search_keys`
- Then use `array_intersect_key()` to filter out the unwanted subarrays
- Then use `array_column()` to create a new array of `first_name` values
- Then glue them together with commas to create a string.

Output:

```
Raj,Giri,Mahesh
```

...This is the answer that future SO readers should be learning from and implementing.  Unfortunately, because it has less votes and doesn't wear the green tick, it will likely get ignored. 
 :(